# Android Studio NFC Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, nfc

Im doing a react-native APP and I'm using https://github.com/Lube/nfc-react-native , I want to try to write and read but my Phone doesn't have the NFC Feature , i tried to install Open NFC on Android Studio but when I put the folder on the add-ons it doesn't appear to install on SDK Manager so I'm kinda stuck here, how can i test NFC on a Emulator? Can i do it?

Operating system : Linux Mint

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, some of the NFC objects like the adapter, will not work.

You can however define the activity filter so that NFC Intent broadcasts will be picked up, and use another app to create those intents. Technically you could listen for NFC indents if the app does not have NFC inside the app as well.

Then at least you can read the NDEF message data (which is prefetched).

Creating mock Tags is also possible. Interacting with objects like NDEF and MifareClassic is far more difficult, since they require an NFC service backend.